# how sort when hashmap value is list of objects by multiple properties java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have like :

```
  Map<String, List<MyState>> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.computeIfAbsent(key, file -> new ArrayList<>()).add(myState);


  map.put("aa",list1..)
  map.put("bb",list2..)
  map.put("cc",list3..)

public class MyState {
    private String state;
    private String date;
}
```

I want to sort the map values `List<MyState>` by `MyState::date` and then by  `MyState::state`

Comment: Sorting `map entries`: `HashMap` is not ordered. Also, lists will have multiple entries. Which of the list elements do you use to sort values of the map itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do so with:

```
Comparator<MyState> comparator = Comparator.comparing(MyState::getDate)
                                        .thenComparing(MyState::getState);
map.values()
   .forEach(l -> l.sort(comparator));
```

Comment: Should that be `MyState::getState` in the `thenComparing` block?

Comment: Or `map.forEach((k, l) -> l.sort(yourComparator))` which I think should be faster.

Comment: @daniu yup that's also another way to go, but I simply avoided that since I am not interested in the map keys as I am sorting the lists.

Comment: But in either case, creating the comparator once before the `forEach` instead of recreating it for each map entry may have a point. For `HashMap`, there’s no performance difference between `map.forEach((k, l) -> …)` and `map.values().forEach(l -> …)`.